# LINQ OrderBy using condition AND Multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

These two work

```
query.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ThenBy(a => a.LastName)
```

Also works

```
query.OrderBy( a=> a.Type == 1 ? a.Name : otherTypeSortOrderColumn)
```

Similarly you can do

```
from a in query orderby a.Name,a.LastName select a;
```

and

```
From a in query orderby (a.type == 1 ? a.Name : otherTypeSortOrderColumn) select a
```

How do you mix both?

For each value of Type I want a different column sort, on which there might or might not be more columns that has to have the "ThenBy" sorting applied

Something like

```
query.OrderBy ( a => a.Type == 1 ? a.Name, A.LastName : a.Type == 2 ? a.Product.Name : ... and so on)
```

Comment: You can use the same field to order in `ThenBy` for types that does not need `ThenBy`. Or for string fields when you don't need to specify desc/asc you can try just  concatenate them (also I maybe missing here some edge cases)

Comment: I mean i know i could do OrderBy(a => condition ..) and repeat the condition with the then by and second sort but i was hoping there would be something more ummm shorter

Comment: What if you write an extension method public static IOrderedEnumerable<TYourType> SmartOrderBy(this IEnumerable<TYourType>) in this method you can dynamically join all kind of linq opderations you like. There is no need for linq to be a one liner.

Comment: @Nehio, What is wrong with last one?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv syntax not working and if you put () it doesnt work either.

Comment: @Klamsi I'm working directly on an IQueryable that needs to be able to be translated into SQL.

Ultimately i chose to write it using ThenBy() and repeating the condition with different column sort so i could achieve what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are not aware that you can join linq operations as ever you like

```
if (thisAndThat)
    orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(...);

if (anotherCondition)
    orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(....);
```

Comment: OP wants to apply condition on per element basis, so this will not help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working AsEnumerable, consider to create an IComparer for it.

```
class PropertyComparer<T, TProperty> : IComparer<T>
{
    public Func<T, TProperty> PropertySelector {get; set;}
    public IComparer<TProperty> PropertyComparer {get; set;} = Comparer<TProperty>.Default;

    public Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        TProperty propertyX = this.PropertySelector(x);
        TProperty propertyY = this.PropertySelector(y);
        return this.PropertyComparer.Compare(propertyX, propertyY);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var customerComparer = new PropertyComparer<Customer, string>
{
    PropertySelector = customer => customer.Name,
    PropertyComparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,
}

IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...
var customersOrderedByName = customers.OrderBy(customer => customer, customerComparer);
```

### There's room for improvement

What if a Customer.Name equals null? Change `IComparer.Compare`:

```
public Compare(T x, T y)
{
    // TODO: decide if NULL comes first or last
    if (x == null)
    {
        if (y == null)
            return 0; // both null
        else
            return +1; // null comes last
    }
    else if (y ==  null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // x and y both not null
```

Comment: Your answer would be what i'd do but it's on an IQueryable on EF Core 5 so nope :) But nice solution !

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to achieve this yet so for now i'm going with a bit more verbose approach to this :

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> keySelector = x =>
                            !x.a.HasValue && x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.c.LastName) ? x.c.LastName :
                            !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && x.d.HasValue ? x.d.Name :
                            !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && !x.d.HasValue && x.e.HasValue ? x.e.Name :
                            !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && !x.d.HasValue && !x.e.HasValue && x.f.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.f.Society) ? x.f.Society : string.Empty;

Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> keySelector2 = x =>
                                !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && x.c.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.c.FirstName) ? x.c.FirstName :
                                !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && !x.d.HasValue && !x.e.HasValue && x.f.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.f.LastName) ? x.f.LastName : string.Empty;



Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> keySelector3 = x =>
                        !x.a.HasValue && !x.b.HasValue && !x.c.HasValue && !x.d.HasValue && !x.e.HasValue && x.f.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.f.FirstName) ? x.f.FirstName : string.Empty;

query = query.OrderBy(keySelector).ThenBy(keySelector2).ThenBy(keySelector3);
```

Where TEntity is the type of the class from IQueryable i'm accessing.

If someone has anything better i'm open to suggestions. I thought about implementing an extension using Linq.Extensions to fiddle around with something cleaner but since this is an edge case it would just be hiding more code behind a pretty front.